# Cloud Firestore + VueJs Auto Generated Numerical Invoice Number

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, auto-increment

I'm trying to build an invoice system for a client of mine using Vue.js and Cloud Firestore.

Once a new invoice is created, my client wants an auto generated invoice number added to every new invoice starting from 0001, 0002, 0003 etc... I guess it would be a numerical ID for every new invoice.

How would i go about doing this with Cloud Firestore? I was looking into the new firebase function:

```
firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment()
```

but its not exactly what i was looking for. Or maybe i'm not using it correctly?

I've been going crazy trying to find a solution or even an idea that would steer me in the right direction.

Thank You!

Comment: Hello. Looking the [official](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue#static-increment) doc I found out that increment() is using Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER and Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER.

Can you elaborate more and share more code regarding the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this another way. I created a document (--invoices--) and in that document i created a field called count and im using the increment function to add to that count when a new document is created.

```
firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment()
```

So, when that count gets updated i grab the last number and update the invoice number field on the new document that was created.